# How to stop Western Digital External HDD from Sleeping

Tags: rhel, external-hdd

I have one  Western Digital External HDD(2TB) connected to Redhat Server with the Partition type Ext3. But I noticed that it goes to 'sleep' mode if no one is accessing it. So if I try to access it, it takes some time to wakeup I want to disabled this feature.

Please advice me which parameter to disable

## OUTPUT

```
sudo /sbin/hdparm /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1:
 readonly     =  0 (off)
 readahead    = 256 (on)
 geometry     = 46589/255/63, sectors = 3906959742, start = 63
```

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the power management with

```
hdparm -B $value /dev/sdx
```

Put that e.g. in `/etc/init.d/boot.local`

Quoting the man page:

> A low value means aggressive power management and a  high  value  means  better performance. Possible settings range from values 1 through 127 (which permit spin-down), and values 128 through 254 (which do not permit spin-
>   down). The highest degree of power management is attained with a setting of 1, and the highest I/O performance with a setting of 254. A value of 255 tells hdparm to disable Advanced Power Management altogether on the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most do).

Comment: I run this command and it gave me the output added in the QUESTION.

Comment: What has the command you executed to do with the one I told you?